# How to store all rows of a column name returned as a MySQL query result in a string array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, string

I want to store all rows of a column name returned as a MySQL query result in a string array. I am new to PHP. I have retrieved the rows but how do I store all rows of a column in an array?

I mean how to iterate the counter of rows and store the column in an array? Or is there any direct function/method call? Please see my code below and its possible ways of storing in an array:

```
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'user';
$dbpass = 'password';

$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die('Error connecting to mysql');
$dbname = 'users';
mysql_select_db($dbname);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT users.email FROM users");

//  AND THEN FINALLY STORING IN A STRING ARRAY:

$array = $result;

//  OR SOMETHING LIKE:

Store($array, $result);

//  OR SOMETHING LIKE:

for(int i = 0; i < $result.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    if (null != $row[0])
    {
        $array[i] = $result[i];
    }
}

//  OR SOMETHING LIKE:

while($null != result.read())
{
    $array.Add($result.Read());
}
```

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/q0gwD). See the [red box](http://goo.gl/OWwr2)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/orrj0) and use either [PDO](http://goo.gl/TD3xh) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/YXyWL) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/b2ATO). Also see [Why shouldn't I use mysql functions in PHP?](http://goo.gl/J5jAo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MySQL Fetch Array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT users.email FROM users");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $array[] = $row;
}
```

This will return an array of associated arrays. The `$row` will contain the index of the column name along with integer index.

For example:

```
echo $row['email'];
//or
echo $row[0];
```

In the end you can get the first row by:

```
$array[0]['email']; //or $array[0][0];
```

**NOTICE:** Do not use MySQL_* for it has been deprecated as of PHP 5.5. Use MySQLi_* or PDO instead.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can do it

```
$rec = mysqli_query("SELECT users.email FROM users");
$data   =   array();
$i=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rec)){
    $data[$i]['column1']    =   $row['column1_from_table'];
    $data[$i]['column2']    =   $row['column2_from_table'];
    $data[$i]['column3']    =   $row['column3_from_table'];
}
```